# Ernst Zermelo's counterexample

Tags: set-theory

According to the book *Real Analysis* by Royden page 6(=1+2+3):

> Given an equivalence relation on a set X, it is often necessary to choose a subset C 
>   of X which consists of exactly one member from each equivalence class. Is it obvious that 
>   there is such a set? Ernst Zermelo called attention to this question regarding the choice of 
>   elements from collections of sets. Suppose, for instance, we define two real numbers to be 
>   rationally equivalent provided their difference is a rational number. It is easy to check that 
>   this is an equivalence relation on the set of real numbers. But it is not easy to identify a set 
>   of real numbers that consists of exactly one member from each rational equivalence class.

I think this question has an answer. A rational equivalence class can be one of the following types:

1- As a set of "sum of a given irrational and all possible rationals", say ${\{\sqrt{2}+r \ | \ r\in \mathbb {Q}}\}$. Suppose a representative of this set is the given irrational, $\sqrt{2}$ in this example.

2- As a set of "sum of a given rational and all possible rationals", say ${\{1+r \ | \ r\in \mathbb {Q}}\}$. Suppose a representative of this set is the *given* rational, $1$ in this example.

So the subset $C$ of $\mathbb R$ which consists of exactly one member from each equivalence class is the collection of irrational and rational numbers and thus $C = \mathbb Q \cup \mathbb I = \mathbb R $.

Is this argument correct?

Comment: Roydon (probably) wants a set where the elements are specified. For instance, there's nothing in your description to say whether $\sqrt5\in C$. (How do you know that $\sqrt5-1$ isn't in your set instead?) ... Also, given two irrationals $r$ and $s$, how do you tell determine whether $r-s$ is a rational number? In particular, is $e-\pi$ rational?

Comment: @Edi , No. The "set of representatives" must contain exactly *one* member of each class. Your set $\mathbb R$ contains, for instance, $0$ and $1$, which belong to the same class because $1-0=1$ is rational.

Comment: And what is $\mathbb I$?

Comment: @user254665 I think the OP is usign $\mathbb I$ for the set of irrationals.

Answer (score 4):

This does not work.

Zermelo's problem is to find a set of reals $C$ such that for each real $r$, there is **exactly one** real $s\in C$ such that $r\sim s$ (that is, $r-s\in\mathbb{Q}$).

If we replace "exactly" with "at least," then this is easy: e.g. just take $C=\mathbb{R}$. Similarly, if we replace "exactly" with "at most," we can just take $C=\emptyset$ (:P).

The difficulty comes when we try to hit each rational equivalence class exactly once. Given a rational equivalence class $W$, we might hope that one of the following will work:

- Pick the smallest positive element of $W$.
- Pick the unique $r$ such that $W$ has the form $\{r+q: q\in\mathbb{Q}\}$.

The former doesn't work because each rational equivalence class is dense; the latter doesn't work since *any* $r\in W$ will have this property.

Finally, we might hope something like the following will work:

- Pick the **simplest** element of $W$.

For instance, if $W$ is the rational equivalence class of $\sqrt{2}$, then clearly $\sqrt{2}$ is the simplest element in $W$. $17+\sqrt{2}$ is also in $W$, but is more complicated.

The problem is: what does "simplest" mean? Any attempt to pin this down will quickly run into trouble. If you play around with this for a while, you'll see what I mean . . .

Comment: "Simplest" element means nothing for the equivalence class of a transcendental real. So this is where you run into  trouble.  Good answer.

Comment: @user254665 I'm not so sure I agree with that, actually - surely we agree that $\pi$ is the "simplest" element of $\{\pi+q: q\in\mathbb{Q}\}$! :P Roughly speaking, it's not the transcendentals that are a problem, it's the "indescribable" real numbers. Intuitively, there are only countably many real numbers you can "describe" in any meaningful sense - how do you pick the simplest element of a rational equivalence class which doesn't contain any describable reals?

Comment: (Note that the argument I sketch about indescribability is informal, and - if pushed too far - is wrong: look up "pointwise definable models of set theory" http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4597. However, the general point *in this context* is valid.)

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that $\pi$ is the simplest member of its equivalence class just because $\pi$ is a such an important number in analysis. Exclusive of your second comment:In general, how do we define "simplest"? (I think the correct response is "We don't.")

Comment: As I posted in OP the book first claims that such a set doesn't always exist. But then it says "Zermelo's Axiom of Choice: Let T be a nonempty collection of nonempty sets. Then there is a choice function on T". Could you please explain me about that? Thanks.

Comment: @Edi: Where does the book claim such a set doesn't always exist?

Comment: @EricWofsey, "Is it obvious that there is such a set?" in the orange box in OP. - and the counterexample follows..

Comment: @Edi: It never claims that the example given is a counterexample, just that it is not obvious that such a set exists in that example.  There is a difference between a statement being false and not obviously true...

Comment: @EricWofsey, so the book's text (in the OP) implies that although always such a set exist by Zermelo's Axiom of Choice but we can't always write down explicit form of that as the example shows.  Am I right?

Comment: @Edi: Exactly.  The Axiom of Choice asserts that such a set always exists, but does not give you any way to explicitly write one down, and in some cases it is impossible to prove that such a set exists without just invoking the Axiom of Choice (or some equivalent axiom).  (To be precise, the book doesn't actually prove that you can't write down such a set explicitly in the example, it just suggests that this seems to be true.)

Comment: @user254665 I would say that in general we don't, but there are certain cases where we do - for instance, if I have computable real numbers $x$ and $y$, it often is useful to say that $x$ is *simpler* than $y$ if there is a computer program (formally: Turing machine) computing $x$ which is shorter than any program computing $y$ (see e.g. "Kolmogorov complexity"). In this definition, it seems likely that $\pi$ is the simplest element of its rational equivalence class since I don't see any way to define any other element except "via" $\pi$, although of course that's not obviously true.

Comment: @EricWofsey, sorry but I still don't understand why this axiom is true when it is an axiom (not a theorem such that we can't avoid it - like Well Ordering Thm that asserts for the existence of an order relation though we can't provide explicit form for some cases) and **it is an axiom**?

Comment: @EricWofsey, the book later says "Zorn's Lemma is equivalent to Zermelo's Axiom of Choice"; if "equivalent" means iff so Zermelo's Axiom of Choice has a 'proof' so is a provable claim and it's acceptable!

Comment: @Edi: The Axiom of Choice only has a proof if you assume Zorn's Lemma, and Zorn's Lemma cannot be proven from the other usual axioms of set theory.